# Simplify boolean equation from truth table

Tags: math, boolean, boolean-logic, truthtable, boolean-algebra

I need help simplifying the following to the simplest terms. Boolean algebra just doesn't quite click with me yet, any help is appreciated. 
(!A!B!C)+(!AB!C)+(!ABC)+(A!B!C)+(A!BC)+(AB!C)
I got it to the following, but I don't know where to go from here:
!A(!B!C + B!C + BC) + A(!B!C + B(XOR)C)

If you are curious and want to check my previous work, I got the original equation from the truth table:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially we have `A(~B~C + ~BC + ~CB) + ~A(~B~C + B~C + BC)`

First Term: `A(~B~C + ~BC + ~CB)`

```
= A(~B(~C + C) + ~CB)
= A(~B(True) + ~CB)
= A(~B + ~CB)
= A((~B + ~C)(~B + B))
= A((~B + ~C)(True))
= A(~B + ~C)
```

---

Second Term: `~A(~B~C + B~C + BC)`

```
= ~A(~C(~B + B) + BC)
= ~A(~C(True) + BC)
= ~A(~C + BC)
= ~A((~C + C) (~C + B))
= ~A((True) (~C + B))
= ~A(~C + B)
```

---

So `First Term` + `Second Term` becomes: `~A(~C + B) + A(~B + ~C)`

```
= ~A~C + ~AB + A~B + A~C
= AxorB + ~A~C + A~C
= AxorB + ~C(~A + A)
= AxorB + ~C(True)
= AxorB + ~C
```

Hence we end up with `AxorB + ~C`